# How do I install a QGIS processing plugin headless for use with qgis_process?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, docker

I'm trying to use the UMEP for processing plugin in a docker container

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing_umep/

After extracting the plugin zip to the plugins directory, it appears in the list but is not "loaded".

```
[root@c4da1ff0ffde /]# qgis_process plugins
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: setapi() is deprecated
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qgis/utils.py:792: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
Problem with GRASS installation: GRASS was not found or is not correctly installed
Problem with SAGA installation: SAGA was not found or is not correctly installed
Available plugins
(* indicates loaded plugins which implement Processing providers)

  processing_umep
* processing
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM lopsided/archlinux

RUN pacman -Syy && pacman --noconfirm -S qgis python-pip python-pandas python-scipy unzip

ENV QT_QPA_PLATFORM offscreen

RUN mkdir -p ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS && \
  echo "[PythonPlugins]\nprocessing=true\nprocessing_umap=true" > ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini && \
  curl https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing_umep/version/0.5/download/ --output umep-processing.zip && \
  mkdir -p ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins && \
  unzip umep-processing.zip -d ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins && \
  rm umep-processing.zip
```

Comment: Not sure you have GRASS installed...neither SAGA. Add them to your Dockerfile and come back with some update about that. You will maybe also have to make your Python install aware of their existence.

Comment: Are GRASS and SAGA required by the UMEP plugin? They aren't listed as requirements.

Comment: I don't actually know. But I read two lines beginning with the word "Problem" which obviously suggested something like this.

Comment: I think it's unrelated, but I'm installing them to make sure.

Comment: Installing grass and saga removed the errors, but the plugin still isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Fixed in QGIS >= 3.16.5 and >= 3.18.0.

Old Answer: It isn't possible to load any plugins headless. That will hopefully change in future.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/41218#issuecomment-768647867